# ASP.NET Web API OData (v4) POST on Entity with SPATIAL PROPERTY

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

What's the right way to POST an Entity with a SPATIAL PROPERTY on ASP.NET Web API OData (v4)?

Serialization on GET works fine, but everything I try in the POST causes the model to go null.

Is POST supported at all?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class PlacesController : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromODataUri] string key)
    {
        var place = new Place()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Location = GeographyPoint.Create(1, 1)
        };

        return Ok(place);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [EnableQuery]
    public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Place place)
    {
        if (place == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        return Created(place);
    }
}

    [DataContract]
public class Place
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public GeographyPoint Location
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

    public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        var edmBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        edmBuilder.EntitySet<Place>("Places");

        var model = edmBuilder.GetEdmModel();

        config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "ODataRoute", routePrefix: "api", model: model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading through below mentioned article it seems possible. You will need to use oDataActionParameters type as input to the post and later in your method cast it to the required type. Mehtod signature will something like below:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RateProduct(ODataActionParameters parameters)
```

check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/odata-actions) for examples and deep dive on this

Comment: Thanks. The binding does work on spatial types when using an action and the spatial type is a "first level" parameter. If the parameter of the action was a Place and the spatial type was a property of the Place, it doesn't work. What's the explanation for that behavior? Serialization works fine and deserialization doesn't. The article you mentioned doesn't directly deal with that.